# Should i go for Hybrid or Native development for a digital Magazine Application?

Tags: android, ios, html, jquery-mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

I need to develop a mobile digital Magazine Application for Android and IOS. Should i go for Hybrid or Native development. is there enough capability in HTML5 AND javascript to make a professional App where user can engage with application.

i want to create Application like

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.leanersmag.leanersmagazine&hl=en_GB&rdid=com.leanersmag.leanersmagazine

https://itunes.apple.com/es/app/leaners-magazine/id572842775?mt=8

Comment: opinion questions aren't really well suited for a programming Q&A site like [so]...

Comment: can you tell me other site where it could well suit.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

- Have you already created application specifications and design?
- What kind of information are you planing to show?

Hybrid mobile applications will give you better flexibility but at the same time you need to specially careful cause great flexibility can soon turn into bad performance.

Read **[this](http://www.gajotres.net/hybrid-vs-native-apps/)** article so you can learn difference between hybrid and native mobile applications.

Magazine apps usually choose hybrid solutions because they can provide near magazine look and feel. Best example is Pulse application (Android and iOS, now owned by LinkedIn). Unfortunately at the same time this is also a worst example, it suffers from numerous bugs (bad page transitions, sometimes you'll get stuck reading same 10 pages in loop).

Native applications don't suffer this fate but you will need to spend much more time making it look spectacular like hybrid applications (again I am talking in context of magazine app).

My advice would be choose hybrid side but be careful when choosing framework. jQuery Mobile is finally fast enough but I don't think it provides you with flexible enough UI for magazine like app. Of course there are much more available frameworks, find something about it [**here**](http://www.gajotres.net/top-7-mobile-application-html5-frameworks/).

In the end, you should also check **[this](https://famo.us/)** framework, it is a newcomer but from what I have so it is lightning fast and flexible enough to server as a basis for magazine app.